# How to edit the php.ini file using Plesk

Tags: apache, php, plesk

Can anyone suggest how I can edit the php.ini file when using Plesk? I am using a Linux based server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ~technically~ you will have to open a shell on the server and edit it using vi or nano or something like that. if you don't have a terminal client you can also enable the java terminal in plesk itself, but it's kinda more trouble than it is worth.

Take a look at putty for a nice free client: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

-sean

Answer (score 1):

Using a shell is the best way since Plesk is really just a GUI for managing users/domains.

You can find the php.ini file on your server by creating a temporary phpinfo page and uploading it

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Then SSH into your server with a shell (Terminal on Mac) to edit it.